# error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive] (español)

Tags: c++

estoy intentando recrear la pagina wordle, pero me topo siempre con el mismo problema

[image: el error está en strcmp]

no se como puedo comparar dos cadenas de caracteres que haya ingresado el usuario

Comment: Tendría que ser solo `strcmp(palabra, jugador.in1)`.  Nota que tiene que ser `==` para comparar, tu estas usando `=`.

Comment: Además la función `strcmp` compara 2 cadenas, no 2 carácteres. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp

Answer (score 0):

El problema es simple, el compilador te lo dice, "invalid conversion from **char** to **char***", es decir "conversión invalida de carácter a puntero a carácter", cuando llamas a la función *strcmp*, le estás pasando como argumentos dos variables de tipo **char** (palabra[x] y jugador.in1[x]), pero dicha función toma dos variables de tipo **char***, lo que tienes que hacer en este caso es eliminar el índice *[x]* de las variables y listo; es decir en vez de escribir **strcmp(palabra[x], jugador.in1[x])**, debes escribir **strcmp(palabra, jugador.in1)** y eso es todo. Ten en cuenta que como no especificas que es lo que tratas de hacer, ni das más detalles, no puedo darte una respuesta más acorde a tu problema; por otra parte recuerda subir código y no capturas de pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas comparar cadenas de caracteres de tipo char lo que podrias hacer es recorrer las dos cadenas de caracteres, asi:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char a[10],b[10];
    bool ver;
    cout<<"ingrese: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"ingrese: ";
    cin>>b;
    int tam=strlen(a)>strlen(b) ? strlen(a) : strlen(b);
    for(int i=0;i<tam;i++){
        cout<<"a: "<<a[i]<<"   b: "<<b[i]<<endl;
        if(a[i]==b[i]){
            ver=true;
        }else{
            ver=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(ver==true) cout<<"son iguales\n";
    else cout<<"son diferentes\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Vas a tener problemas si las cadenas son de diferente tamaño. Y puedes reducir el código estableciendo ver en true antes de entrar al ciclo; y dentro del ciclo no hacer nada si son iguales.